# Date difference between two rows

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2012, date-difference

I have not done excel programming. I have a table as follows:

### Excel Part

```
CreatedTime Id 
05/04/2015 1000 
05/10/2015 1000 
05/12/2015 1000
05/01/2015 1001
05/05/2015 1001
05/03/2015 1002
05/13/2015 1002
```

What I want is:

```
CreatedTime Id  Days_Between_Actions
05/04/2015 1000 4
05/10/2015 1000 6
05/12/2015 1000 2
05/01/2015 1001 1
05/05/2015 1001 4
05/03/2015 1002 3
05/13/2015 1002 10
```

This formula works for entries corresponding to every 'Id' except the first entry of each 'Id' -> `=IF(A3 = "05/01/2015",1,DAYS(A3,A2))`. But for the first entry corresponding to every 'Id' the formula has to be `=IF(A2 = "05/01/2015",1,DAYS(A2,"05/01/2015")+1)`.

1. Is an easier way to do this?
2. I currently have to use one formula for the first entry and another formula for other entries corresponding to an 'Id' and this makes it very difficult to propagate this for the entire table. Is there a single formula I can use?

### SQL Part

I'm using a query like -> `select distinct convert (date, CreatedTime) as CreatedTime, Id from database.table where createdtime between '2015-05-01 00:00:00' and '2015-05-15 23:59:59' order by Id, CreatedTime`

3. So, is there an easier way to get what I want by changing the query?

Comment: It's on SQL-Server. My bad for tagging MySQL.

Comment: what version of sql server?

Comment: Didn't get the logic for `Days_Between_Actions` can you explain a bit more

Comment: So, for a particular 'Id' say 1002, the first entry is on 05/03/2015. So the "Days_between_Actions" would have to be 3 i.e. 3 days from the beginning of the month. The next entry for 'Id' 1002, shows it was on 05/13/2015, so the difference between the previous date of action 05/03/2015 and this would give us 10 days. Hope it's clear. Sorry for the ambiguity!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution in excel to have only one formula working in all rows:
`=IF(A2 = "05/01/2015",1,DAYS(A2,IF(B2=B1,"04/30/2015",A1))`

Comment: I'm happy it works! The difference is just where do you start inserting formula:)

Comment: Oh no! I didn't mean the positional difference. If you look at what worked was the swap in the inner IF condition between "04/30/2015" and A1 (as per your example). I should've pasted the output from the exact cell to show the difference. Thanks anyways! :)